# Permission error when using sparklyr with Hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, sparklyr

I am trying to get `sparklyr` to work on a cluster with Hadoop. When I run `sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", version = "2.8.5")`

I get this error message:

```
Error in force(code) : 
  Failed during initialize_connection: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=rstudio, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:hadoop:drwxr-xr-x
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:189)
...
```

The user rstudio is what I created for RStudio server. How do I fix the permissions to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using hadoop superuser (looks like its `hdfs` in your case), you need to create an HDFS home directory (`/user/rstudio`) for your rstudio user, and change its ownership so that rstudio is the owner. See http://www.hadooplessons.info/2017/12/creating-home-directory-for-user-in-hdfs-hdpca.html?m=1 for details.